# TomeEE Java Version 5

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

I installed TomEE plus version 1.5.1. It has Tomcat version 7. Can TomEE be used with Tomcat 6? It is possible?

Having a quick search on Google, doesn't give anything back.

Answer (score 0):

Consider OpenEJB instead of TomEE.

- [Manual Installation](http://tomee.apache.org/manual-installation.html)